# How to iterate the loop for a matched pattern and print the count using awk

Tags: awk

i have below multipath output.

```
mig_1 (3624a9370908ba6a5e68a464600014087) dm-11 PURE,FlashArray
size=5.0T features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='queue-length 0' prio=1 status=active
  |- 0:0:2:3 sdeo 129:0  active ready running
  |- 0:0:3:3 sdep 129:16 active ready running
  |- 1:0:2:3 sdeq 129:32 active ready running
  `- 1:0:3:3 sder 129:48 active ready running
mig_2 (3624a9370908eb6a5f69a4646000140bb) dm-10 PURE,FlashArray
size=7.0T features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='queue-length 0' prio=1 status=active
  |- 0:0:2:2 sdkg 66:320 active ready running
  |- 0:0:3:2 sdkh 66:336 active ready running
  |- 1:0:2:2 sdki 66:352 active ready running
  `- 1:0:3:2 sdkj 66:368 active ready running
```

Would like to check how many active paths exist for each LUN. If the LUN is not having /active ready running/ it should decrease the count. Tried the below way, but it is not providing the required result. It is providing the total count for all the LUN's, also size is coming in different line.

```
 cat multi | awk '/dm-1/ {print $1"\t"$2} ; /^size/ {print $1} ; /active ready running/ {a++} END {print a}'
mig_1   (3624a9370908ba6a5e68a464600014087)
size=5.0T
mig_2   (3624a9370908eb6a5f69a4646000140bb)
size=7.0T
8
```

Expected output like below:

```
Disk  #1:  mig_1  (3624a9370908ba6a5e68a464600014087)  size=5.0T  active_paths:4
Disk  #2:  mig_2  (3624a9370908eb6a5f69a4646000140bb)  size=7.0T  active_paths:4
```

Kindly advise how to achieve the above output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples(only), please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk` version.

```bash
awk '
/^mig_[0-9]+/{
  if(found && val1 && val2 && count){
    print "Disk  #" ++count2,val1,val2,"active_paths:"count
    count=val1=val2=found=""
  }
  val1=$1 OFS $2
  found=1
  next
}
found && /^size=[0-9]+/{
  val2=$1
  next
}
found && /active ready running/{
  count++
}
END{
  if(found && val1 && val2 && count){
    print "Disk  #" ++count2,val1,val2,"active_paths:"count
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you for the update. Yes, it is working.. But i am looking for a one liner. So developing that..

Comment: @veeranjaneyareddy, Here you go with one-liner form of solution: `awk '/^mig_[0-9]+/{if(found && val1 && val2 && count){print "Disk  #" ++count2,val1,val2,"active_paths:"count;count=val1=val2=found=""};val1=$1 OFS $2;found=1;next}
found && /^size=[0-9]+/{val2=$1;next} found && /active ready running/{count++} END{if(found && val1 && val2 && count){print "Disk  #" ++count2,val1,val2,"active_paths:"count}}'   Input_file` Please do run it and confirm me how it goes?

Comment: @veeranjaneyareddy, Make sure you are running this command as a one-liner(the previous comment one), try it once and let me know how it goes then.

Comment: Great code. I tested it on a file with the output repeated, giving 4 lines with the right info. HOWEVER, when I modified one of the lines to have no "active ready running" paths, that particular device was not picked up, thus only three lines were printed in the output. Basically, the first if statement only prints for a device with at least one active path. This will not catch devices with all paths down.

Comment: @JayRugMan, Thank you. IMHO; answers are always given by OP's shown samples and expected output only, so if its not there in samples I can't include that logic to code. But yes anyone(OP all users) can get inspiration from posted codes and could play around with it, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 2):

Standing on the shoulders of giants, my answer is based on @RavinderSingh13's answer. I pointed out in the comments that aside from being great awk code, it will not print a line for devices with no active paths, thus missing devices with all-paths-down. Being a storage support engineer for over 5 years and a storage admin for just over two, I know first-hand that having a line with "0" active paths is probably the most critical. So, I revised RavinderSingh13's awk a little to account for this. I also slimmed it down by cutting away some of the unnecessary bits

```
awk '
/^mig_[0-9]+/{
  if(found){
    if(!active){
      active="ALL PATHS DOWN"
    }
    print "Disk  #" ++count,val1,val2,"active_paths:"active
    active=val1=val2=""
  }
  else{
    found=1
  }
  val1=$1 OFS $2
  next
}
/^size=[0-9]+/{
  val2=$1
  next
}
/active ready running/{
  active++
}
END{
  if(!active){
    active="ALL PATHS DOWN"
  }
  print "Disk  #" ++count,val1,val2,"active_paths:"active
}
' mpath.txt
```

mpath.txt (note that I don't have access to a SAN or server with multipathed devices, let alone one with non-active/healthy paths, so I made up the output "failed faulty stopped" - regardless, these arbitrary strings have no impact on my awk code modifications - it will work on any path line in the output that is not strictly "active ready running")

```
mig_1 (3624a9370908ba6a5e68a464600014087) dm-11 PURE,FlashArray
size=5.0T features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='queue-length 0' prio=1 status=active
  |- 0:0:2:3 sdeo 129:0  active ready running
  |- 0:0:3:3 sdep 129:16 failed faulty stopped
  |- 1:0:2:3 sdeq 129:32 active ready running
  `- 1:0:3:3 sder 129:48 active ready running
mig_2 (3624a9370908eb6a5f69a4646000140bb) dm-10 PURE,FlashArray
size=7.0T features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='queue-length 0' prio=1 status=active
  |- 0:0:2:2 sdkg 66:320 failed faulty stopped
  |- 0:0:3:2 sdkh 66:336 failed faulty stopped
  |- 1:0:2:2 sdki 66:352 failed faulty stopped
  `- 1:0:3:2 sdkj 66:368 failed faulty stopped
mig_1 (3624a9370908ba6a5e68a464600014087) dm-11 PURE,FlashArray
size=5.0T features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='queue-length 0' prio=1 status=active
  |- 0:0:2:3 sdeo 129:0  active ready running
  |- 0:0:3:3 sdep 129:16 active ready running
  |- 1:0:2:3 sdeq 129:32 active ready running
  `- 1:0:3:3 sder 129:48 active ready running
mig_2 (3624a9370908eb6a5f69a4646000140bb) dm-10 PURE,FlashArray
size=7.0T features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='queue-length 0' prio=1 status=active
  |- 0:0:2:2 sdkg 66:320 active ready running
  |- 0:0:3:2 sdkh 66:336 active ready running
  |- 1:0:2:2 sdki 66:352 active ready running
  `- 1:0:3:2 sdkj 66:368 active ready running
```

I hope my modifications are welcome and I hope RavinderSingh13 gets 98% of the credit.

Final Output:

```
...

Disk  #1 mig_1 (3624a9370908ba6a5e68a464600014087) size=5.0T active_paths:3
Disk  #2 mig_2 (3624a9370908eb6a5f69a4646000140bb) size=7.0T active_paths:ALL PATHS DOWN
Disk  #3 mig_1 (3624a9370908ba6a5e68a464600014087) size=5.0T active_paths:4
Disk  #4 mig_2 (3624a9370908eb6a5f69a4646000140bb) size=7.0T active_paths:4
```